# giving a javascript number fixed width after decimal while remaining a number

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want a javascript number to always be a length of four.
So `10` should display as `10.0`
and `9` should display as `9.00`
It can't be of type `string` since I input it into a [highcharts gauge](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/), and it must be a number and not a string.
The problem being, that the width is always changing...so I want the width to be constant, while staying a number.
In PHP this is not a problem...
Is this possible in javascript?
That an number should just show with its decimal places? like `1.00`

Comment: Is the number always integer?

Comment: Pretty much anything that processes numbers will ignore unnecessary precision, so formatting this to send to the chart is pointless. Send the actual number to the chart, and format the display number as needed.

Comment: You only thing you can do is  `number.toFixed(1)` but you will have a string.

Comment: @jcubic - that will work on 10.0 with 1 decimal place but not 9.00 with 2 decimal places. But you are right in that toFixed() gives a string.

Comment: @gavgrif you can test if number is less then 9 then use `toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @jlbriggs The number is always a float, never an integer, (and of course, should never be a string)

Comment: Checked the gauge, how would display three digit numbers? Say 200, you want to display it as '200.'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **jlbriggs** already explained - number passed as point value will have shortest possible precision. What you could care about is how `dataLabel` is displayed (number under black arrow) - you can control what is displayed using `dataLabels.format` or [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.dataLabels.formatter).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ufygd53/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [5],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function() {
            var number = this.y,
                    prec = 2;
            while(number > 10) {
                number /= 10;
                prec--;
            }
            return this.y.toFixed(prec);
          }
        }
    }]
```

If you need to change display of tooltip or axis labels - it will be similar change - look for proper `formatter` in Highcharts API reference.